# Can selenium driver detect which platform it is running in

Tags: selenium, java

I need to verify that a certain condition happens on different platforms, e.g. a link of an app for iphone only happens on ios devices, and similarly, a link of an app for android only happens on android devices.

My question is if there is a way for selenium driver to detect which platform it is on so I can run a test something similar to:

```
if (driver == ios) {
    do something...
} else if (driver == android) {
    do something...
}
```

Comment: I assume your code is actually opening the driver, so have that code set a flag that can be accessed from your test scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the solution:

```
DesiredCapabilities capability;
if (capability.getPlatform().is(Platform.ANDROID)) {
    // do something...
} else if (capability.getPlatform().is(Platform.MAC) {
    // do something...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this using the `capability.setPlatform()` key/value pair from `DesiredCapabilities` of Selenium. You can read about the official documentation [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities.html).

Answer (score 0):

To determine the OS of mobile operating system you can use javascript.

Following is the javascript to detect android phone

```
function isAndriod() { 
 if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) {
 return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

And following is the javascript to detect the IOS devices

```
function isIOS() { 
 if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) {
 return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

You can execute this javascripts using `JavascriptExecutor` of selenium and based on return value you can perform your future operations.